# How do I subscribe to a CiviCRM developer email list/group?

Tags: api, email, developer

I'd like to get more involved with the CiviCRM development process.  How can I subscribe to the API or General Development email list/discussion group that I keep hearing about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find a list of possible discussion groups/email list, navigate to http://lists.civicrm.org/lists/lists and click on the list you're interested in.  On the list's page, click the subscribe button to the left.  You'll get an email verifying your interest.  Confirm your subscription with the link in the email you receive.